# Query PDO with two classes

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

Good Evening, I have a problem with PHP PDO queries created from two classes. Here's the first class that is used for DB connection:

```
class PDOConn {
    protected $HOST = "host";
    protected $DATABASE = "db";
    protected $USER = "usr";
    protected $PASSWORD = "pwd";
    protected $CONN;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CONN = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->HOST.";dbname=".$this->DATABASE,$this->USER,$this->PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Second is used to register and sign-in a user:

```
class insLog{
    protected $db;
    protected $TheHash = "PASSHASH";

    function __construct(){
        $db = $this->db = new PDOConn();
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->db = null; 
    }

    public function reg($nome,$cognome,$password,$email){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM utenti WHERE cognome = :cognome OR email = :email");
        $stmt->bind_param(array(":cognome"=>cognome,":email"=>email));
        $stmt->execute();
        //Here I wanna use if row instead if there's id so > 0...
        echo $stmt['id'];
        if($stmt['id'] == ""){echo "Lol";}
        //...
    }
}
```

Bearing in mind that I'm noob into OOP and I'm here to learn and it's almost 3 hours that I'm tring to figure out how to solve, now I wanna ask: what I'm doing wrong What is the problem with my code? Thank you alot in advance.

Comment: There's no `bind_param` method in PDO, it's called `bindParam()`. `bind_param` is in mysqli.

Comment: `$stmt['id']` makes no sense. `$stmt` isn't an array, it's a PDO statement. You need to use `$row = $stmt->fetch()` to get a row of results, then `$row['id']` to get the ID from it.

Comment: Thank you for answare... I get this error: [12-Feb-2015 18:45:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOConn::prepare() in /home/hmrxipsn/public_html/php/c.logreg.php on line 13 The line 13 is the line of the query... I checked DBConn and it's correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDO method to bind parameters is `bindParam`, not `bind_param`. And you need to use `fetch` to read a row of results. It will return `false` if no rows were matched by the `SELECT`.

```
public function reg($nome,$cognome,$password,$email){
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM utenti WHERE cognome = :cognome OR email = :email");
    $stmt->bindParam(array(":cognome"=>cognome,":email"=>email));
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(!$row){echo "Lol";}
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answare...
I get this error:
[12-Feb-2015 18:45:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PDOConn::prepare() in /home/hmrxipsn/public_html/php/c.logreg.php on line 13

The line 13 is the line of the query...

I checked DBConn and it's correct...

Comment: Add `public function getConnection() { return $this->CONN; }` method to your PDOConn class, and then use `$this->db->getConnection()->prepare`. Also use `$cognome` and `$email` instead of `cognome` and `email`.

Comment: @RedHayley You need to define a `prepare` method in your `PDOConn` class. Or you need a method that returns the PDO connection, and use that when you set `$this->db`.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you alot Barmar!!
So helpful! :)